# Web server not working in android

Tags: java, android, webserver

I am trying to create a simple multi threaded server in android the code which i am using do not give me any error but warnings please have a look at my code and tell the mistakes which i have the code works fine if  run it as a java application Here goes the code:

```
 package dolphin.developers.com;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;


public   class AnroidWebServerActivity extends Activity  {
     ServerSocket serverSocket;

{





    try {

        runserver();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    public void runserver() throws Exception {


        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
        acceptRequest();

    }

    private void acceptRequest() throws Exception{

        while(true){

            Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
            Log.v("tag", "server is ruunning!!");

            ConnectionHandler ch = new ConnectionHandler(s);
            ch.start();
        }

    }


       public class ConnectionHandler extends Thread {

           PrintWriter pw;
           BufferedReader br;

           Socket s;
           public ConnectionHandler(Socket s) throws Exception{
               this.s = s;

               br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
               pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());



           }

           @Override
        public void run() {
             Looper.loop();
               try{

               String reqS = "";


               while (br.ready() || reqS.length() == 0){

                   reqS += (char) br.read();
        }

               System.out.println(reqS);

               HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(reqS);
               HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse(req);


               pw.write(res.response.toCharArray());
               pw.close();
               br.close();
               s.close();


               }
               catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace(); 
                   }
               }


       }


       public class HttpRequest{
           public String filename ;

        public HttpRequest(String request){

               String lines[] = request.split("\n");
               lines = lines[0].split(" ");
               filename = lines[1];


           } 

       }
             public class HttpResponse{

                 HttpRequest req;

                 String root;

                 String response;

                 public HttpResponse(HttpRequest request){
                     req=request;

                     root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";

                     File f  = new File(root + req.filename);


                     try{


                     response+= "HTTP/1.1 200 \r\n";
                     response+= "Apache Server /1.0";
                     response+= "Content-Type: text/html \r\n";
                     response+="Connection: close \r\n";
                     response+= "Content-Length:" + f.length() + "\r\n";
                     response+= "\r\n";

                     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);


                     int s;

                     while ((s = fis.read()) != -1){

                         response += (char)s ;


                     }

                     fis.close(); 


                 }catch(FileNotFoundException fg){
                     response = response.replace("200", "404");

                 }

                     catch(IOException e ){

                         response  = response.replace("200", "500");

                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
             }

}

}
```

Logcat:

```
07-18 14:34:23.367: W/System.err(1249): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-18 14:34:23.388: W/System.err(1249):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
07-18 14:34:23.398: W/System.err(1249):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:54)
07-18 14:34:23.398: W/System.err(1249):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98)
07-18 14:34:23.398: W/System.err(1249):     at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:202)
07-18 14:34:23.398: W/System.err(1249):     at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:127)
07-18 14:34:23.407: W/System.err(1249):     at dolphin.developers.com.AnroidWebServerActivity.acceptRequest(AnroidWebServerActivity.java:47)
07-18 14:34:23.407: W/System.err(1249):     at dolphin.developers.com.AnroidWebServerActivity.runserver(AnroidWebServerActivity.java:40)
07-18 14:34:23.407: W/System.err(1249):     at dolphin.developers.com.AnroidWebServerActivity.<init>(AnroidWebServerActivity.java:30)
07-18 14:34:23.407: W/System.err(1249):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-18 14:34:23.407: W/System.err(1249):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-18 14:34:23.407: W/System.err(1249):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
07-18 14:34:23.407: W/System.err(1249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
07-18 14:34:23.407: W/System.err(1249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-18 14:34:23.407: W/System.err(1249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-18 14:34:23.407: W/System.err(1249):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-18 14:34:23.427: W/System.err(1249):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 14:34:23.447: W/System.err(1249):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 14:34:23.447: W/System.err(1249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-18 14:34:23.447: W/System.err(1249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 14:34:23.447: W/System.err(1249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 14:34:23.447: W/System.err(1249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-18 14:34:23.447: W/System.err(1249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-18 14:34:23.447: W/System.err(1249):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It would be easier for us if you show the warning messages instead.

Comment: so sorry i forgot that.

Comment: please have a look now

Comment: It looks like some code is missing.  Is  try {runserver(); happening inside the constructor?

Comment: Depending on whether or not you're just trying to learn this, you might want to skip reinventing the wheel and just use an existing HTTP server? Android includes HttpServerConnection that can be used for this, and there are many third party libraries that do it (search for Android HTTP server).

Comment: Your exception is also pretty self-explanatory, you shouldn't use the main thread for networking, because you'll block the UI. Android is trying to tell you not to do that. See the "worker threads" part of this doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run the server directly from the Activity's main thread.  This will block your application from running and eventually cause it to crash.  You need to run the server on a background thread.

The proper way is to move your server thread into a Service, which you can read more about here: http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html.  This article will give you some other options for using threads directly within your Activity: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html.

Comment: @user2589896 start a new thread that will execute your web server

Comment: is this correct    new Thread(new runnable(){public void run(){runserver()}).start();

Comment: @user2589896 Please accept my question if its the right answer :)

Comment: i want to ask that suppose i am running a avd for api level 17 then the ip of the host computer and the avd will be different or same.